how to Delet overlapping faces in geomotry nodes

https://obsidian-data-1326798899.cos.ap-guangzhou.myqcloud.com/question.blend
copy this link to download
I made these two, and after merging the geometry, I want to use the distance between the positions of the faces as 0 to remove the overlapping faces, but what's wrong with not recognizing geometric nodes.
The one above is scanned after subdividing the cube, splitting the edges, and then turning the curve, with a cover.
I used the distance between the point position of the curve before scanning and the final face position to determine, and deleted the geometry that was equal to 0, but I couldn't delete it.




Start by applying the geonodes modifier and deleting the faces manually in Edit Mode. If the process appears to work, it's a good moment to try to implement it in geonodes. But I suspect it may be the case you need not just to delete faces but to cut them first and then delete only overlapping parts of the faces.

Wow, it's true. I found that merging geometric nodes has helped me remove overlapping faces. What I should be thinking about now is how to calculate the faces inside the geometry

It's a very strange thing,I just didn't get it,why I can't delete the cube's faces by using distance boolean

Could you make screenshots in English, please ? Identifying GN nodes by colors and sockets is quite time consuming...

here is my blender file's download links
